# IPMI on HP Proliant DL120 G5

Tags: ipmi, hp-proliant

I have a question: Our HP Proliant DL120 G5  have 2 cards, one for networking and the other used with ipmi. Is there any way to use only the network card for both, data traffic and IPMI? (In this way we would need only 1 iface card in the switch instead of two)

Bye!! And thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

HP states that sideband support isn't available on this class of hardware.

From [the quickspecs on lo100c](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12468_div/12468_div.html):

> The shared NIC feature (also known as
>   sideband support) is not available  on
>   all ProLiant 100 series servers that
>   use the LO100c cards. For example,
>   this capability is not available on
>   ML100 series Generation 5 as well as 
>   the HP ProLiant DL180 G5 and DL120 G5
>   servers. LO100c shared NIC support  is
>   available for the HP ProLiant ML150
>   G3, ML110 G4, and ML115 servers  with
>   Version 2.10 firmware.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if a system comes with a separate ipmi-only ethernet interface then you are stuck using two separate physical connections on your switch.

Since the data requirements for ipmi are generally fairly low you can always just stick a cheap second switch in your rack just for ipmi access.  If course, that assumes you have room in your rack...